# Как задать для SearchView поиск по определённым элементам из списка ListView

Tags: java, android, строки, listview, android-search-view

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой вот проблемой.

В окне поиска пишу определенные буквы или слово, и выдаёт некорректные результаты. В чем заключается некорректность: В listview приходят данные из файла json , которое лежит в приложении. В файле довольно много данных, и если искать в поиске слово которое напрочь отсутствует в listview и в файле json , то поиск мне всё равно выдает список из множества элементов.

**содержание файла json:**

```
[{
        "streams": [
          "http://potok:9000/index"
        ],
        "commercials": true,
        "stationUrl": "http://site.ru",
        "description": "Первое цифровое танцевальное радио. Лучшие танцевальные хиты.",
        "network": "Club",
        "iconUrl": "http://www.site.ru/stations/logo.jpg",
        "name": "Радио 1"
      },
      {
        "streams": [
          "http://potok:9002/index"
        ],
        "commercials": true,
        "stationUrl": "http://site.ru",
        "description": "Популярные программы с участием суперзвезд.",
        "network": "Pop",
        "iconUrl": "http://site.ru/index/stations/radio.jpg",
        "name": "радио 2"
      },
      {
        "streams": [
          "http://potok:9001/index"
        ],
        "commercials": true,
        "stationUrl": "http://site.ru",
        "description": "Радиостанция, круглосуточно вещающая рок-музыку.",
        "network": "Retro",
        "iconUrl": "http://site.ru/stations/index2.jpg",
        "name": "Радио 3"
      }]
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы поиск выполнялся только по строкам "description" и "name" ?

главное активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, DirectoryAdapter.Listener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, PlayerView.Listener {


    ...
    private SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        adapter.filterStations(query);
        directory.scrollToPosition(0);
        return true;
    }
```

**DirectoryAdapter**

```
public class DirectoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirectoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static int MODE_DIRECTORY = 0;
    private static int MODE_FAVORITES = 1;
    public boolean colorTitleStation = true;

    public interface Listener {
        void onStationClicked(final Station station);
    }

    private final List<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
    private Listener listener;
    private int mode;

    public DirectoryAdapter() {
        stations.addAll(getStations());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Station station = stations.get(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(station.getName());
        holder.descriptionView.setText(String.format("%s (%s)", station.getDescription(), station.getNetwork()));

        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(station.getIconUrl()).fit().centerCrop().transform(new Transformation() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
                PaletteCache.generate(station.getIconUrl(), source);
                return source;
            }

            @Override
            public String key() {
                return station.getIconUrl();
            }
        }).into(holder.iconView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                final Palette palette = PaletteCache.get(station.getIconUrl());
                if (palette == null)
                    return;

                final Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                if (swatch != null) {

                }

                // ставим цвет заголовка названия станций
                if (!colorTitleStation){
                    if (swatch != null) {
                        holder.nameView.setTextColor(swatch.getRgb());
                        colorTitleStation = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    colorTitleStation = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onStationClicked(station);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stations.size();
    }

    private List<Station> getStations() {
        if (mode == MODE_FAVORITES) {
            return Favorites.getFavorites();
        }
        return Directory.getStations();
    }

    public void showFavorites() {
        mode = MODE_FAVORITES;
        updateStations();
    }

    public int showDirectory() {return stations.size();}

    public void setListener(final Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    public void filterStations(final String query) {
        List<Station> filteredStations = queryStations(query);
        updateStations(filteredStations);
    }

    public void updateStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        removeFilteredStations(filteredStations);
        addFilteredStations(filteredStations);
    }

    public void updateStations() {
        updateStations(getStations());
    }

    private void removeFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        final Iterator<Station> iterator = stations.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Station station = iterator.next();
            if (!filteredStations.contains(station)) {
                final int position = stations.indexOf(station);
                iterator.remove();
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        for (Station station : filteredStations) {
            if (!stations.contains(station)) {
                final int position = findPosition(station);
                stations.add(position, station);
                notifyItemInserted(position);

            }
        }
    }

    private int findPosition(final Station station) {

        int position = 0;
        while(position < stations.size() && stations.get(position).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName()) < 0) {
            position++;
        }

        return position;
    }

    private List<Station> queryStations(final String query) {
        final List<Station> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

        final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(query);
        for (Station station : getStations()) {
            if (isEmpty || station.matchesQuery(query))
                filtered.add(station);
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView iconView;
        TextView nameView, descriptionView;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iconView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            nameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            descriptionView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите логику по поиску нужных елементов масива в класс активити, как в примере. так у вас сразу будет доступ к нужному параметру, если вам понадобится получить елемент списка
[Example activity class](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/wrdlbrnft/searchablerecyclerviewdemo/ui/activities/MainActivity.java)